# Multiple functions on one element

Tags: jquery

I am trying to run two functions on one element, one after the other. Currently, I have a input that copies whatever is in it to another input box. What I need is that second input box to then become part of a calculation.

Here is the relevant HTML:

```
    <p class="text"><span class="set_name"></span> read to me what your current outstanding balance is.

   $<input name="statement_balance_c" id="statement_balance_c" class="statement_balance_c"></input></p> //this box populates the lien input below

<tr>
    <td>Borr Est of Value $
      <input type="text" name="value"  id="value" title="Enter number only"/> </td>
    <td>Loan Amount $<input type="text" name="lien" id="lien" class="lien"  title="Enter number only"/></td>
    <td>LTV<input type="text" name="ltv" id="ltv" title="If this is above 55% proceed with caution" readonly/></td> /*this input uses jquery to calculate the loan to value based  on the inputs of value and lien */
</tr>
```

And the jQuery for both functions:

```
    $(".statement_balance_c").on('keyup',function(){
$(".lien").val($(this).val());
});

$('#lien').change(function(){
    var loan_amoumt = document.getElementById('lien').value;
    $('#first_mortgage').attr('value', loan_amoumt );
    $('#first_lien_table').toggle();
    var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('value').value) || 0;
    var lien = parseInt(document.getElementById('lien').value) || 0;
    var ltv = (lien/value)*100 + '%';
    $('#ltv').val(ltv);
    if(this() > '60%'){
        $('#ltv').css('background-color', 'red');
    }
    else{
        $('#ltv').css('background-color', '#2EFE2E');
    }
});
```

The first function works perfectly, but the second does not. The second function DID work before I added the first function, and will work if I change the number to something different manually. Any ideas?

Comment: So, why the down vote? Is the question not clear enough? Do I need more info? I know no one is obligated to explain themselves, but doing so can help me post better questions in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should trigger the change event you've created, either on the keyup, and/or on a change:

```
$(".statement_balance_c").on('keyup', function () {
    $(".lien").val($(this).val()).change();
});
```

Or

```
$(".statement_balance_c").on('change',function(){
    $(".lien").val($(this).val()).change();
});
```

Comment: That got me a little closer... Now the ltv field just reads Infinity% unless I manually change the lien field to something else. Is there a way to prevent the second function from firing until both the value and lien fields are completed?

Comment: You could change the function doing the calculation to only do it if both fields have values.

Answer (score 0):

Using a combination of j08691's guidance and an onfocus event I was able to get this done without returning an error. So now, the code looks like this:

```
$(".statement_balance_c").on('change',function(){
    $(".lien").val($(this).val()).change();
    });

$('#lien').change(function(){
var loan_amoumt = document.getElementById('lien').value;
$('#first_mortgage').attr('value', loan_amoumt );
$('#first_lien_table').toggle();
var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('value').value) || 0;
var lien = parseInt(document.getElementById('lien').value) || 0;
var ltv = (lien/value)*100 + '%';
$('#ltv').val(ltv);
if(this() > '60%'){
    $('#ltv').css('background-color', 'red');
}
else{
    $('#ltv').css('background-color', '#2EFE2E');
}
```

and for the HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="ltv" onfocus="calculate_ltv()" id="ltv" title="If this is above 55% proceed with caution" readonly />
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Why the down vote? Is my answer not clear enough? Does it not adequately solve the problem? Is it because I answered my own question and that is somehow frowned upon? Again, telling me why will help me be a better part of this community....